# How do i parse a list in this format in python something:some07therthing:another thiing?

Tags: python, string

I know this is a noob question! But I'm new to python and i can't seem to find a way to get the index of the second occurance of `":"`!
When i use [re.findall(":", string)] it returns a list!
same happens when i use `re.search` or `string.index(":")`

How do i get the position of `(":")` ?

Example: string = "2020:turquoise"
I want to store those three values in different variables...

[

```
line = "2020:turquoise"
x = re.search(":", line)
y = x.start()
year = line[:y]
color = line[(y+1):]
```

]

this works fine! But i can't seem to do it when there are three values that i need to assign to different variables! An example string would be 
string = "2021:red:notagoodyear"

how do i store those three strings into different variables?

Comment: Can you edit your question to show the list in a code block? E.g. ‘[“my item 1”, ”my item 2”]’

Comment: Could you share an axample input and the eexpected output ?

Comment: Just did! sorry I'm new to python and stackoverflow ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably don't need regular expressions for this:

```
line = "2020:turquoise"
year,color = line.split(":")

line = "2021:red:notagoodyear"
year,color,comment = line.split(":")
```